# How to use cloudformation to create an ecs cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I would like to use a cloudformation template to create my ecs cluster instead of spinning it up by hand, but I have yet to find a way. Is this simply not implemented yet, where you can create an ecs cluster as a resource in your cloudformation template, seems a bit odd they did not include that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like there is nothing special about ECS that you should not be able to do via cloudformation.

here is a ECS quick stack cf template: https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon-ecs-cloudformation/Amazon_ECS_Quickstart.template

Checkout: 
http://www.cloudtp.com/2015/02/04/getting-started-ec2-container-service-ecs/

The key in the cloud formation template is really the AMI id + ECS_CLUSTER definition in /etc/ecs/ecs.config. If you get that right it's basically a normal EC2 CF build.

Also, looks like there are newer AMIs for ECS. Here are the latest:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_container_instance.html

Comment: Thanks for the links. In the quick start template there is just the default cluster. But if you provide your own cluster name, you have to have it created already. What I was hoping for is to create my own ecs cluster as a resource.

Comment: You should be able to to create a [cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-cluster.html) and then use the [`DependsOn`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) resource attribute on your services.

Comment: Google search brings me here..... The problem is after I did lots of configuration on a cluster, the exported template doesn't carry the changes like services, tasks, containers etc. Does anyone know how to put all the changes to a template?